# Count and RowNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sampe Table:

```
CusID   Order     Status
3001    Hotdog    Paid
3001    Sausage   Paid
3001    Burger    Unpaid
3002    Sausage   Paid
3003    Burger    Paid
3003    Hotdog    Paid
3002    Hotdog    Paid
3001    Burger    Paid
3002    Burger    Unpaid
```

Desired Ouput

```
Row    CusID   NumOfOrdersPaid
1      3001    3
2      3002    2
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (
      ORDER BY CusID
      ) row
    ,count(CASE STATUS
        WHEN 'Paid'
          THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
        END) AS NumOfOrdersPaid
  FROM Orders
  ) X
WHERE x.r BETWEEN 1
    AND 2
GROUP BY CusID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from    
(Select CusID,row_number() over (order by CusID) r,
count(case Status when 'Paid' then 1 else null end)
 AS NumOfOrdersPaid from Table1 Group By CusID) X
where x.r between 1 and 2;
```

[**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61652/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CusID ASC) AS Row, CusID, NumOfOrdersPaid FROM MyTable) As List
```

Comment: Ok, I get it, I missed a bit